# How to get the middle position of a button where it ends?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-button

I have a button which is oval shaped. I want to know the middle position of the button but in last coordinates, where button ends.

I have tried taking help of below code however, it is not working.

```
View v;
int pos= v.getX()+ v.getWidth();
```

However the position its returning goes out of view area. I have tried doing this using this below code as well.

```
Rect rectf = new Rect();
v.getLocalVisibleRect(rectf);
int pos = v.getX() + rectf.width
```

Comment: Do you want the coordinates of the centre or the coordinates of the end?

Comment: coordinates of end will do for me but my button is oval shaped!!

Answer (score 0):

```
int location[] = new int[2];
v.getLocationOnScreen(location);
int pos = location[0] + v.getMesuredWidth();
```

Comment: There lies the issue...I did this too however, it cross end point of view

Comment: What my exact requirement is that I want to draw a line from a button end to another buttons x position so that they look connected.